# How do I use mpi4py to iterate a list of object whose size is bigger than the number of processor

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I'm trying to parallel 4,000,000 calculations in 32 nodes (16 cores in each). Is it possible that I finish these calculations in one job using the mpi4py module in Python, if the wall time limit permits?

For example, if one processor finishes its calculation, it will move forward to the next undone calculation (I already have a small function to detect this calculation has been done or not).

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi ! Are you looking for a master/slave example in Python/mpi4py? See https://gist.github.com/mgmarino/2773137 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own solution:

```
    from mpi4py import MPI
    def scatter_jobs():
        comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
        rank = comm.Get_rank()
        size = comm.Get_size()
        data = [i for i in range(4000000)]
        for i in range(rank,len(data),size):
            # Do something with data[i]
```

Comment: if `Do something` timing is independent of the index `i`, then that will work just fine. otherwise, you might have some imbalance (e.g. some tasks finish sooner than other) and the overall parallel efficiency will drop. if you are in the latter case, you'd rather consider a master/slave architecture as described in a previous comment

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm new to parallel computing, and didn't think of that... In my case, each processor is iterating it's own but the same list, and yes it's using index `i`. Would this decrease the parallel efficiency? I thought the processors are independent from each other.

Comment: If i understand correctly your solution, each MPI tasks is processing roughly the same number of iterations. So if all iterations take the same amount of time regardless the index i, then all MPI tasks will complete roughly simultaneously, and this is ideal with respect to parallel efficiency. If not, then some tasks will take longer than others, and the elapsed time wil be roughly the one of the slowest MPI task (e.g. the other tasks will just wait for the slowest one), and that would be bad for parallel efficiency.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, there's no significant taken-time difference among those iterations, so I'm safe for now :) But thanks for the explanation, I do need to look into the master/slave architecture.